# Pandas read_sql columns not working when using index_col - returns all columns instead

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas

I'm using `pandas.read_sql()` command to get data from my postgresql database.
The SQL query is created generically with many columns from which I only want to get specific columns using one column as index.
Creating an example table `test_table` like this:

```
column1 column2 column3
1       2       3
2       4       6
3       6       9
```

I tried to use the `index_col` and `columns` parameter from `pandas.read_sql()` to get `column1` as index and `column2` as data (and neglecting `column3`!). But it always returns the whole table. Also when writing `columns=['column1', 'column2']` nothing changes...

I'm using python 2.7.6 with pandas 0.17.1 - Thanks for help!

**Example Code:**

```
import pandas
import psycopg2
import sqlalchemy


def connect():
    connString = (
        "dbname=test_db "
        "host=localhost "
        "port=5432 "
        "user=postgres "
        "password=password"
    )
    return psycopg2.connect(connString)

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
            'postgresql://',
            creator=connect)
sql = (
    'SELECT '
    'column1, '
    'column2, '
    'column3 '
    'FROM test_table'
)
data = pandas.read_sql(
    sql,
    engine,
    index_col=['column1'],
    columns=['column2'])
print(data)
```

Comment: why don't you want to change your 'select' query? and i guess you want to use `pandas.read_sql_query()` instead

Comment: The sql query should only be build once and used afterwards by different functions, picking specific columns from it. I did not use `read_sql_query()`, because it has no `columns` parameter (which is not really doing what i want for now) - for my code `read_sql()` and `read_sql_query()` do not differ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the argument `columns` did not work for you because you were using sql statement instead of providing it with your table name.

As mentioned from pandas website:

> columns : list, default: None List of column names to select from sql
>   table (**only used when reading a table**).

Therefore, I think if you try:

```
pandas.read_sql('test_table', engine, index_col=['column1'], columns=['column2'])
```

`columns` argument will actually work.

Comment: It's a pity that it doesn't work with sql statements